# Synaptic won't open in Ubuntu 20.04 -- An error occurred

Tags: package-management, synaptic

Today I installed synaptic on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.  For awhile, it ran just fine.  Then I decided to try to add the opera browser repository and things started to go wrong.  Now when I try to run synaptic, I get a popup containing the following message:

An error occurred.  The following details are provided:
E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

I get the  option to close the window, and the app won't open.  I can't uninstall it either, I get the same error message.

I'd like to either "fix" it or remove it and re-install it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking a question before I looked around a bit.  I edited the sources.list file and deleted line 54 -- the one that was added when I tried to put the opera repository in as a source.

Problem solved, synaptics now working fine.  I'll find another way to use opera with Ubuntu 20.04.